# fabric.js How to draw a straight line with arrows, and the end of the line can be dragged

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to draw a polyline:

1. With arrows
2. With endpoint control, you can drag and drop, and you will be able to connect with other objects in the future (I don’t know whether to use fabric.js Control or draw a circle by myself)

My current implementation is like this: The line consists of 5 parts:
Two endpoints + two arrows + line body.

When dragging the end point, the arrow position, the arrow angle, and the coordinates of the line body are synchronously modified.

this is demo `fabric.PolygonalLine` is the key to the problem

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById("c"))

    fabric.PolygonalLine = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
        // hasControls: false,
        // hasBorders: false,
        // selectable: true,

        points: [],

        sControl: null,
        eControl: null,
        centerControl: null,
        // 垂直方向或者水平方向
        controlMoveDirection: "",

        sArrow: null,
        eArrow: null,

        initialize: function (points, options = {}) {
            this.points = points || []
            this.callSuper("initialize", options)

            let len = this.points.length
            let defaultOpt = {
                hasBorders: false,
                hasControls: false,
                originX: "center",
                originY: "center",
            }

            this.sControl = new fabric.Circle({
                fill: null,
                radius: 4,
                strokeWidth: 1,
                stroke: "rgba(57, 87, 239, 0.8)",
                left: this.points[0].x,
                top: this.points[0].y - 8,
                ...defaultOpt,
            })
            this.eControl = new fabric.Circle({
                fill: null,
                radius: 4,
                strokeWidth: 1,
                stroke: "rgba(57, 87, 239, 0.8)",
                left: this.points[len - 1].x,
                top: this.points[len - 1].y + 8,
                ...defaultOpt,
            })
            this.sArrow = new fabric.Triangle({
                left: this.points[0].x,
                top: this.points[0].y,
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                // selectable: false,
                lockMovementX: true,
                lockMovementY: true,
                ...defaultOpt,
            })
            this.eArrow = new fabric.Triangle({
                left: this.points[len - 1].x,
                top: this.points[len - 1].y,
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                angle: 180,
                // selectable: false,
                lockMovementX: true,
                lockMovementY: true,
                ...defaultOpt,
            })
            canvas.add(this.sArrow, this.eArrow, this.sControl, this.eControl)

            this._bindEvents()
        },

        _bindEvents() {
            this.sControl.on("moving", (e) => {
                this.sArrow.set({
                    left: e.pointer.x,
                    top: e.pointer.y + 8,
                })

                this.points[0].x = e.pointer.x
                this.points[0].y = e.pointer.y

                this.points[1].x = e.pointer.x

                canvas.requestRenderAll()
            })

            this.eControl.on("moving", (e) => {
                this.eArrow.set({
                    left: e.pointer.x,
                    top: e.pointer.y - 8,
                })

                this.points[3].x = e.pointer.x
                this.points[3].y = e.pointer.y

                this.points[2].x = e.pointer.x

                canvas.requestRenderAll()
            })

            this.sControl.on("selected", (e) => {
                console.log("---106-11-selected---", this)
            })

            this.on("selected", (e) => {
                console.log("---106---selected--", e)
            })
            this.on("moving", (e) => {
                console.log("---110--moving---", e)
            })
        },

        render(ctx) {
            ctx.save()
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(this.points[0].x, this.points[0].y)
            for (let i = 0; i < this.points.length - 1; i++) {
                let point = this.points[i]
                ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y)
            }
            ctx.lineTo(this.points[3].x, this.points[3].y)
            ctx.stroke()
            ctx.restore()
        },
    })

    // ---------------------------content---------------------
    let rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        left: 10,
        top: 5,
        fill: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
    })
    let circle = new fabric.Circle({
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        radius: 25,
        left: 200,
        top: 205,
        fill: "#aac",
    })
    let line = new fabric.PolygonalLine(
        [
            {
                x: 35,
                y: 70,
            },
            {
                x: 35,
                y: 120,
            },
            {
                x: 225,
                y: 120,
            },
            {
                x: 225,
                y: 190,
            },
        ],
        {
            text: "",
            stroke: "red",
            strokeWidth: 2,
            strokeLineCap: "butt",
            strokeDashArray: [10, 5],
        }
    )

    canvas.add(rect, circle, line)
    canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: 0, y: 0 }, 2)
    canvas.renderAll()
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/460/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

But it feels awkward to do so. Does any friend have a better way? Or provide an idea. Grateful.

Comment: Don't ignore the red message before posting a question. Please [edit] it and include a textual [mve] in the question itself

Comment: Oh,  [mve] should be =>  [mcve]

Comment: @AlonEitan This is really the smallest code that can explain the situation. I don't know how to reduce them

Comment: I meant creating the example in the question itself as I just did, not **just** including link to jsfiddle

Comment: @AlonEitan  I see. This is my first question. I'll pay attention next time. Thank you.